# 'material-ui' does not contain an export named 'withStyles'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, material-ui

My package.json looks like this. The app was working fine until a while ago suddenly i get this error.

```
    "@material-ui/icons": "1.0.0-beta.42",
"chartist": "0.10.1",
"classnames": "2.2.5",
"material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.41",
"npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
"perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-chartist": "0.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.2.0",
"react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
"react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "1.0.17",
"react-swipeable-views": "0.12.12"
```

My component looks like this
import React from "react";
    import {
    withStyles,
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardContent,
    CardActions,
    Typography
    } from "material-ui";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";

```
import profileCardStyle from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/profileCardStyle";

function ProfileCard({ ...props }) {
const { classes, subtitle, title, description, footer, avatar } = props;
return (
<Card className={classes.card}>
<CardHeader
classes={{
root: classes.cardHeader,
avatar: classes.cardAvatar
}}
avatar={<img src={avatar} alt="..." className={classes.img} />}
/>
<CardContent className={classes.textAlign}>
{subtitle !== undefined ? (
<Typography component="h6" className={classes.cardSubtitle}>
{subtitle}
</Typography>
) : null}
{title !== undefined ? (
<Typography component="h4" className={classes.cardTitle}>
{title}
</Typography>
) : null}
{description !== undefined ? (
<Typography component="p" className={classes.cardDescription}>
{description}
</Typography>
) : null}
</CardContent>
<CardActions className={classes.textAlign + " " + classes.cardActions}>
{footer}
</CardActions>
</Card>
);
}

ProfileCard.propTypes = {
classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
title: PropTypes.node,
subtitle: PropTypes.node,
description: PropTypes.node,
footer: PropTypes.node,
avatar: PropTypes.string
};

export default withStyles(profileCardStyle)(ProfileCard);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `withStyles` of MUI :

```
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'
```